# SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac using psycopg

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am working on a bot on telegram that analyzes user messages and stores them in the postgre database using the python psycopg library (I use the chat_id as the primary key of the user =. I build the bot using botogram, obviously I created as many handles as the messages to be analyzed. In the first handle the problem is addressed by the compiler and resolved. Moving on to the second handle with name_stop function, it inexplicably takes me back to the first handle (I repeat, already overcome) with an ambiguous error that I was unable to find on the net: `SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac`.

```
@bot.command("start")
def start_command(chat, message, args):
    bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
        'chat_id': chat.id,
        'text': 'Benvenuto nel bot, cosa desideri fare?',
        'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard_selection)}) #scelta
    item = chat.id
    item2 = "db"+str(chat.id)
    try:
        cloc = connloc.cursor()
        cloc.execute("INSERT INTO corona(chat_id) VALUES (%s)", (str(item),))
        connloc.commit()
    except:
        return
@bot.process_message
def name_loc(chat, message):
    item = chat.id
    item3 = "db"+str(chat.id)
    cloc = connloc.cursor()
    print(cloc.mogrify("SELECT * FROM corona WHERE chat_id = %s", (item,)))
    varcheck = cloc.execute('SELECT * FROM corona WHERE chat_id = %s', (str(item),))
    itemvarop = cloc.fetchone()
    varop = []
    for item in itemvarop:
        varop.append(item)
    for i in result:
        if message.text == i and varop[1] == None and varop[2] == None and varop[3] == None and varop[4] == None:
            item = i
            item2 = chat.id
            cloc = connloc.cursor()
            cloc.execute("UPDATE corona SET locpar = %s WHERE chat_id = %s",(str(item),str(item2),))
            connloc.commit()
            for t in result[i]:
                        keyboard_stops = {"keyboard": [[{"text": t} for t in pair] for pair in zip(result[i])]}
            bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
                            'chat_id': chat.id,
                            'text': 'Perfetto, seleziona la fermata in cui ti trovi',
                            'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard_stops)}) #fermata 1


@bot.process_message
def name_stop(chat, message):
     item = chat.id
     item3 = "db"+str(chat.id)
     cloc = connloc.cursor()
     varcheck = cloc.execute("SELECT * FROM corona WHERE chat_id = %s", (str(item),))
     itemvarop = cloc.fetchone()
     varop = []
     for items in itemvarop:
         varop.append(items)
     for i in result:
      for t in result[i]:
         if message.text == t and varop[1] != None and varop[2] == None and varop[3] == None and varop[4] == None:
             item = t
             item2 = chat.id
             cloc = connloc.cursor()
             cloc.execute("UPDATE corona SET stoppar = %s WHERE chat_id = %s",(str(item),str(item3),))
             connloc.commit()
             bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
                                    'chat_id': chat.id,
                                    'text': 'Ora invece, seleziona la località che vuoi raggiungere',
                                    'reply_markup': json.dumps(keyboard_locpo)}) #città 2
```

When it parses the second handle message (defined with the variable t), it brings me back to the following output:

```
File "v.1.0.py", line 525, in name_loc
    varcheck = cloc.execute('SELECT * FROM corona WHERE chat_id = %s', (str(item),))
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
```